# Undefined array key 0 wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 76

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, capabilities

as in the title. I tried to find solution, but people got quite another issue...

Line 76:

```
$post = get_post( $args[0] );
        if ( ! $post ) {
            $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
            break;
        }
```

My head just exploding. What can I do?

Comment: You have an error from a Plugin or function inside the Theme. So remove all plugins, use a default theme and switch back one by one active to find the plugin or theme that cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks for response. I just deleted this plugin and found alternative one.

Comment: Your questions is not completely clear to me. Could you clarify your situation and what is not working? Also, from your comment it seems you've found an alternative solution. It would be useful to share your solution here so other users can also benefit.